# How to solve error when getting max value in a row (EF Core Linq)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Accessing a table with values: Id ImageId Score .
Need to get the highest score of each simular ImageId.

Ex:

```
1 a1 10 points
2 a1 30 points
3 b1 15 points
```

Want: `a1 30 points and b1 15 points`

Code used:

```
public async Task<List<HistoryEntry>> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                => await _db.History.GroupBy(a => a.ImageId).Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First()).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Error:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: h.ImageId, ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: HistoryEntry ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Hopefully this functionality is coming with EF Core 6.0 which should be released soon. Until then, use the workarounds from the linked posts, in your case something like `_db.History.Select(a => a.ImageId).Distinct().SelectMany(key => _db.History.Where(x => x.ImageKey == key).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).Take(1))`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in your code is to change order:

```
var groupedResult  = await _db.History.GroupBy(a => a.ImageId).ToListAsync();
return groupedResult.Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First());
```

EF cannot translate such nested queries into SQL - hence your error. In this solution grouped result is materialized in memory, so such nested queries won't cause issues.
Be careful, though - this is surely not optimal solution if there are lots of records in DB, but in few records case it will do its work.

Comment: I see, what is considered as optional?

Comment: I think, I'd go with DB view, but there might be some other possibility to get such data using only EF

Comment: actuallly I'm getting a new error on return:   `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Application.Core.Domain.History.HistoryEntry>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Application.Core.Domain.History.HistoryEntry>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) `

Comment: add ToList() at the end of return statement